# Suppose $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of the vector space $V$. Show that $U + W$ = $sp(U \cup W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am not sure where to start with this one, any help would be appreciated. I tried using the definition of a span but I couldn't see where to go from there.

Comment: What does $U+V$ mean? Must elements in this subspace lie on $sp(U\cup V)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof
Let $W=\text{Span}(S_1)$ and $U = \text{Span}(S_2)$.
Let $a_i,b_j,c_k\in\mathbb{R}\quad\forall i,j,k\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$ be given.
To show that $U+W = \text{Span}(S_1\cup S_2)$,
we will show that first show that $U+W\subseteq \text{Span}(S_1\cup S_2)$.
Let $v\in U+W$.
Then, $v = u+w$, where $u\in U$ and $w\in W$.
We have $u=\sum^{n}_{i=1}a_iu_i$ and $w=\sum^m_{j=1}b_jw_j$, where $w_j\in S_1$ and $u_i\in S_2\quad\forall i,j\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$.
Hence, $v=\sum^{n}_{i=1}a_iu_i + \sum^m_{j=1}b_jw_j$.
This is a linear combination of vectors that are either in $S_1$ or in $S_2$.
Then, $v\in \text{Span}(S_1\cup S_2)$.
Since $v$ was chosen arbitrarily, we thus have $U+W\subseteq \text{Span}(S_1\cup S_2)$.
We then show that $\text{Span}(S_1\cup S_2)\subseteq U+W$.
Let $v\in\text{Span}(S_1\cup S_2)$.
Then $v =\sum^l_{k=1}c_kz_k$, where $z_k\in S_1\cup S_2$.
Notice that $z_k$ is in either in $S_1$ or in $S_2$.
Hence, if we replace $z_k$ by vector $w_j\in S_1$ or $u_i\in S_2$ and regroup them, then we have $v = \sum^{n}_{i=1}a_iu_i + \sum^m_{j=1}b_jw_j$.
Then by definition we have shown that $v=\text{Span}(S_1)+\text{Span}(S_2)=W+U$, which means $\text{Span}(S_1\cup S_2)\subseteq U+W$.
Therefore, U+W = \text{Span}(S_1\cup S_2).
Q.E.D

Answer (score 2):

The subspace $U+V$ contains $U$ and $V$, so it contains the span of $U\cup V$. Conversely any vector in $U+V$ is the sum of a vector in $U$ with a vector in $V$, so it belongs to the span of $U\cup V$.

Answer (score 1):

To show equality of two spaces, show containment both ways.

Suppose $U = \langle u_1, \dots, u_k \rangle, W = \langle w_1, \dots, w_l \rangle$.

Something of the form $u+w$ is obviously in the span of $U \cup W$, because $u$ is in the span of $U$ and $w$ is in the span of $W$.

Conversely, something in the span of $U \cup W$ can be written as $\alpha_1 u_1 + \dots + \alpha_k u_k + \beta_1 w_1 + \dots + \beta_w w_l$, which is precisely writing it as "something in $U$ + something in $W$".